# How to get Hoenn/Sinnoh Sound in HeartGold?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation, pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

In Pokemon HeartGold I heard that we can catch Pokemon from another regions (Hoenn and Sinnoh) using Hoenn/Sinnoh Sound.

But how can I get that Hoenn/Sinnoh sound and where can I used this feature?

Comment: http://www.serebii.net/heartgoldsoulsilver/hoennsinnoh.shtml

Comment: In case the link will get broken, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/heartgoldsoulsilver/hoennsinnoh.shtml):

#### Hoenn Pokémon

To get Hoenn Pokémon, all you need to do is *turn the PokéGear Radio onto the Pokémon March station* on a **Wednesday**. On Wednesdays, the Pokémon March Channel is the "Hoenn Sound" show. If you have this playing while going through the areas and the wild Pokémon may be a Pokémon whom is originally from Hoenn.

#### Sinnoh Pokémon

To get Sinnoh Pokémon, all you need to do is *turn the PokéGear Radio onto the Pokémon March station* on a **Thursday**. On Thursdays, the Pokémon March Channel is the "Sinnoh Sound" show. If you have this playing while going through the areas and the wild Pokémon may be a Pokémon whom is originally from Sinnoh.

There is one problem with this method however, you have to switch the radio back to the station after each battle so there may be some back and forth going if you're hunting for a specific Pokémon.

Comment: is it possible to set your DS date/time to simulate a Wednesday or Thursday in the game?

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer You can change the date on your DS, but this will usually disable every time-based event in every game for 24h.